# Shell to Bash Script

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

```
fld=$(mediainfo Fixing\ One\ of\ Linux\'s\ Biggest\ Flaws.mp4 | awk -F " : " 'NR==10 {print $2}'); 
mkdir "$fld"
```

I'm attempting to get Performer from mediainfo's output.
Line number 10 contains:

```
Performer                                : The Linux Cast
```

In this file's case I just want "The Linux Cast" by itself.
I can't get this to work in a bash script. I have inline file separator set but the brace expansion is throwing me off. Files downloaded with youtube-dl and read with mediainfo.

Not understanding why the code won't work in the shell. I probably should use sed or other core utility.

Just trying to organize files by the content creator.

Comment: Please edit your post to add the actual output you are getting from the `mediainfo` program, the desired output, and the undesired output the bash script generates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than relying on line number, match on the `Performer`:

```
fld=$(
  mediainfo "Fixing One of Linux's Biggest Flaws.mp4" |
    sed -n 's/^Performer[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*//p'
)
```

Or with GNU `grep`:

```
fld=$(
  mediainfo "Fixing One of Linux's Biggest Flaws.mp4" |
    grep -Po '^Performer\s*:\s*\K.*'
)
```

Or use `exiftool`:

```
fld=$(
  exiftool -q -p '$Artist' "Fixing One of Linux's Biggest Flaws.mp4"
)
```

Comment: Thnx so much. I figured I was over thinking things. All the provided solutions work perfectly.

Comment: @Dark_Stoner Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.

Comment: I hit the check mark Is that correct?. It's working wonderfully now. Thanks again.